# Which encryption method is this

Tags: linux

I am testing a site and have come across this password ...

```
aW/hY4XQjFpq1ZGzoO5cZ.
```

I have noticed a "." at the end and not sure which encryption method would create this. Any ideas would be useful.

Comment: Do you suspect that this is a hashed password? Do you have more samples?

Comment: I see several Google searches trying to reverse this hash, but why do you think this is a hash? I think it's a password. [1](https://forum.hashkiller.co.uk/topic-view.aspx?t=10616&m=83864) [2](http://www.turkhackteam.org/tht-yardim-merkezi/1307009-aw-hy4xqjfpq1zgzoo5cz-bunu-nasil-kirabilirim.html)
 [3](http://www.v4-team.com/cc/showthread.php?p=1664207)

Comment: Where did you find this? In /etc/shadow? Context will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, [multiple](https://forum.hashkiller.co.uk/topic-view.aspx?t=10616&m=83864) people trying [to reverse](https://md5hashing.net/QnA/question/nJAjeZZKSBvNPjGr7) this [online](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jsvjSJsbhbsJ:hackforums.net/printthread.php%3Ftid%3D5232224%20&cd=8&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl&client=firefox-b). If you're not "cacaocaca1" and "Vicci", there's a big chance this password is simple, and easy to guess in a dictionary attack.

> That looks like the right size and charset for a crypt MD5, except its 
>   missing the salt and prefix. Normally the output from crypt MD5 would
>   look something like this.
>
> $1$rasmusle$jrCf9Xc61lNMIQse/NJ1q.
>
> With your hash I'd expect to also see the type and salt before the
>   hash itself. In my example it would be "1" and "rasmusle". Maybe they
>   have the salt hardcoded elsewhere and are stripping it out of the
>   final hash you're fetching. Or they're just using something that uses
>   the same encoding scheme as crypt MD5 with a final hash thats the same
>   bit size.